# How to run SQLite query asynchronously on background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, asynchronous, android-sqlite

I have a big database which takes time to find needed information. So I decided to use RxJava to make this process asynchronous.

```
            @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            final String query = s.toString();
            Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Cursor>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Cursor> subscriber) {
                    subscriber.onNext(database.search(query));
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Cursor>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Cursor cursor) {
                    scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
                }
            });
        }
```

But query is running on main thread: EditText where I entering text is freezing.

My question is how to run SQLite query asynchronously on background thread?

Comment: why don't you want to use LoaderManager (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)?

Comment: @atlascoder, I tried to use LoaderManager, but I did not find the way how I can pass query parameter to get new cursor with new values. I had same problem - it worked on UI thread

Comment: It is ordinal practice to use LoaderManager together with ContentProvider. but if this is too complicated, you may use `AsyncTask`. Not good example of using `AsyncTask` is here http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: or more simple example http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/60331340133/very-simple-example-of-a-loader-and-loadermanager

Answer (score 0):

Probably this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html
will suite for you.

Besides, here is short implementation for you, but this is not RxJava.

Firstly, you need to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`, and usually this interface is implemented by Activity (or Fragment).

In `onCreateLoader`, a `CursorLoader` should be created and returned. Here is just an example with MyCursorLoader as descendant of `CursorLoader`, where you can perform connection to database and queries.

In `onLoadFinished` you have to treat cursor with results of query.

Please, consider the link to android.com, mentioned above.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // start loading data using LoaderManager of Activity
    // third argument only has sense in this case
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

private static final String ACTIVITY_NAME = "main_activity";

private void treatCursorRow(Cursor cursor){
    // treat record from cursor
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // this callback is called by LoaderManager in order to obtain CursorLoader
    // here a new one loader is created
    // created loader will be processed by LoaderManager
    return new MyCursorLoader(this, ACTIVITY_NAME);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // this callback is called when loader finishes load cursor
    // you don't need to destroy loader - just tread the data
    if(data != null)
        while(data.moveToNext())
            treatCursorRow(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // here you can do something
    // relevant to cancelling of loading data
    // in example, when you have an event that cancels current
    // loading and restarts new one
}

class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_database";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private String name_param;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, String activity_name) {
        super(context);
        name_param = activity_name;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        // assuming, that we have implemented SQLiteOpenHelper
        // to treat sqlite-database
        MyDatabaseHelper dbh = new MyDatabaseHelper(
                MainActivity.this,
                DATABASE_NAME,
                null,
                DATABASE_VERSION
        );
        return dbh.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name=?",
                new String[]{ name_param }
        );
    }

}

}
```

Another way, is in using of `ContentProvider` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html .

In this way you can separate data layer and business logic. Your data access will be abstracted to uris. 
Using `ContentProvider`, you define your queries within it and load data using Uri:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return getContentResolver().query(
            YourContentProvider.SOME_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
}
```

This is convenient way if you have more than one or two customers of your data (Activities or Fragments) - you will use just predefined uris rather repeating sql queries or creating many CursorLoaders `descendands`.

Moreover, `ContentProvider` may be used from outside your app if you want.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.